# How to detect QR codes from images in Go?

Tags: go, image-processing, qr-code

How can I detect QR codes when processing the pixels of an image?

The image might be pixelated (low-fidelity), noisy (missing or extra pixels in a line), blurry (antialiasing), or be at an angle (image skew). Simply looping through the pixels seems like it would require some sort of line detection and then you could figure out a good calculate of the number of expected blocks between the three (or four) different corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an image processing library to detect QRCodes. I’ve used [go-zxing](https://github.com/makiuchi-d/gozxing) in the past which is 100% native go.

You will need to be familiar with the [go image package](https://pkg.go.dev/image) that’s part of the standard library.